# Import-Csv add a column then Export-Csv

Tags: powershell, csv

I am often given a CSV and asked to add information to it.  For a simplified example I may be handed the following CSV and asked to get the *lastlogontimestamp* for each user

[image: CSV]

In order to achieve this I did the following

```
$csv = import-csv users.csv
$report = "User Audit_{0:dd-MM-yyyy_HHmm}.csv" -f (Get-Date)
$csv | ForEach-Object {
    $user = ""
    $user = get-aduser $_.user -Properties lastlogontimestamp | Select-Object @{ N = 'LastLogonTimestamp'; E = { [DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogonTimestamp) } }
    [pscustomobject]@{
        User = $_.User
        'First Name' = $_.'First Name'
        'Last Name' = $_.'Last Name'
        'LastLogonTimestamp (AD)' = $user.lastlogontimestamp
    } | Export-Csv $report -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

This works very well but creating it can be time consuming for spreadsheets with lots of columns and is subject to human error during the pscustomobject construction.  So my question is - rather than manually constructing the pscustomobject is there a way to code it (using the column headings to populate each key and value), after which I can append my new additions?

Comment: Move `| Export-Csv` down one line and remove `-Append` - this way `Export-Csv` doesn't have to re-open the file and write one row at a time - much faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Select-Object` with `*` to copy all existing columns and use [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2) to add new ones:

```sh
$report = "User Audit_{0:dd-MM-yyyy_HHmm}.csv" -f (Get-Date)

import-csv users.csv | ForEach-Object {

    $user = get-aduser $_.user -Properties lastlogontimestamp
 
    $_ | Select-Object *, 
        @{ N = 'LastLogonTimestamp (AD)'; E = { [DateTime]::FromFileTime($user.LastLogonTimestamp) } }

} | Export-Csv $report -NoTypeInformation
```

Also, as suggested by [Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen), move `Export-Csv` to the end of the pipeline and remove `-Append` to improve performance. Otherwise the file would be opened and closed for each row, which is very slow.

I also took the liberty to slightly refactor the code to remove the first `Select-Object` statement, which is no longer needed. Also you can pipe `Import-Csv` directly into `ForEach-Object`, without using a temporary variable.

Comment: @Itchydon You can also remove the first `Select-Object` statement, as I just did in my code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the reason why it's time-consuming is that you're appending your results for each user. You could reduce how long it takes by simply assigning all your results to a variable and then exporting those results to a CSV at the end like this:

```
$csv = import-csv users.csv
$report = "User Audit_{0:dd-MM-yyyy_HHmm}.csv" -f (Get-Date)
$results = $csv | ForEach-Object {
    $user = ""
    $user = get-aduser $_.user -Properties lastlogontimestamp | Select-Object @{ N = 'LastLogonTimestamp'; E = { [DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogonTimestamp) } }
    [pscustomobject]@{
        User = $_.User
        'First Name' = $_.'First Name'
        'Last Name' = $_.'Last Name'
        'LastLogonTimestamp (AD)' = $user.lastlogontimestamp
    } 
} 
$results | Export-Csv $report -NoTypeInformation
```

You could also ignore the variable all together and pipe your results directly to `Export-Csv`

```
$csv = import-csv users.csv
$report = "User Audit_{0:dd-MM-yyyy_HHmm}.csv" -f (Get-Date)
$csv | ForEach-Object {
        $user = ""
        $user = get-aduser $_.user -Properties lastlogontimestamp | Select-Object @{ N = 'LastLogonTimestamp'; E = { [DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogonTimestamp) } }
        [pscustomobject]@{
            User = $_.User
            'First Name' = $_.'First Name'
            'Last Name' = $_.'Last Name'
            'LastLogonTimestamp (AD)' = $user.lastlogontimestamp
        } 
    } | Export-Csv $report -NoTypeInformation
```

In terms of human error. I'm not sure what exactly is "prone to human error" in your code so I can't make a recommendation there.

UPDATE - This should get you what you're looking for

```
$csv | ForEach-Object {
Get-AdUser $_.user -Properties lastlogontimestamp | Select-Object UserPrincipalName, SamAccountName, GivenName, SurName, @{ N = 'LastLogonTimestamp'; E = { [DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.LastLogonTimestamp) } }       
} | Export-Csv $report -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: The time consuming bit is constructing the pscustomobject (not running the script).  I am asking about automating the pscustomobject creation

Comment: @Itchydon Take a look at my update.

Comment: No it doesn't.  That is querying AD for the info as opposed to copying it from the old csv.  Only the last column lastlogontimestamp should be queried from AD

Comment: @Itchydon The Get-AdUser query returns GiveName, SurName, SamAccountName, and UserPrincipalName all by default but I understand why you would want to keep the original values from the CSV the same.

Comment: This was only an example - often the other columns data is not from AD.  Thanks for looking